# Use paypal's sandbox to test a subscription button

Tags: javascript, apache, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

So here's the deal, I'm not going to beat around the bush, my goal is to make a subscription button so that people can subscribe to my site for around 20€/month. To do this, I'm using the paypal button that I've modified in order to have all the features I need:
[image]

```
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=MY_CLIENT_ID&vault=true&intent=subscription" data-sdk-integration-source="button-factory"></script>
<script>
  paypal.Buttons({
      style: {
          shape: 'pill',
          color: 'silver',
          layout: 'vertical',
          label: 'subscribe'
      },
      createSubscription: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.subscription.create({
          /* Creates the subscription */
          'plan_id': 'MY_PLAN_ID'
        });
      },
      onApprove: function(data, actions) {
        alert(data.subscriptionID); // You can add optional success message for the subscriber here
        console.log(data);
        var subscriptionID = data.subscriptionID;

              // Envoie du numéro d'abonnement au serveur via une requête Ajax
              var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
              xhr.open('POST', 'includes/traitement.php', true);
              xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
              xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
                  // Réponse du serveur
                  console.log(xhr.responseText);
                }
              };
              var params = 'subscriptionID=' + subscriptionID;
              xhr.send(params);
      },
      onCancel(data) {
            console.log(data);
          },
          onError(err) {
            console.log(err);
          }
  }).render('#paypal-button-container-MY_PLAN_ID'); // Renders the PayPal button
</script>
```

The essential functions for me are failure reception, abandonment and payment, to ensure that the user gets what he paid for!
To do the test I recreated the same code to modify some elements to use paypal sandbox:

```
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=CLIENT_ID_OF_MY_BUSINESS_ACCOUNT_SANDBOX&vault=true&intent=subscription" data-sdk-integration-source="button-factory"></script>
<script>
  paypal.Buttons({
    style: {
      shape: 'pill',
      color: 'silver',
      layout: 'vertical',
      label: 'subscribe'
    },
    createSubscription: function(data, actions) {
      return actions.subscription.create({
        /* Creates the subscription */
        'plan_id': 'MY_PLAN_ID',
        subscriber: {
          email_address: 'sb-sbngw26946178@business.example.com' // Adresse email du compte Business de test
        }
      });
    },
    onApprove: function(data, actions) {
      alert(data.subscriptionID); // Vous pouvez ajouter un message de réussite facultatif pour l'abonné ici
      console.log(data);
      var subscriptionID = data.subscriptionID;

      // Envoi du numéro d'abonnement au serveur via une requête Ajax
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('POST', 'includes/traitement.php', true);
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
          // Réponse du serveur
          console.log(xhr.responseText);
        }
      };
      var params = 'subscriptionID=' + subscriptionID;
      xhr.send(params);
    },
    onCancel(data) {
      console.log(data);
    },
    onError(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }).render('#paypal-button-container-MY_PLAN_ID'); // Affiche le bouton PayPal
</script>
```

So I read in the documentation, at least that's what I understood, that you have to put `www.sandbox.paypal.com` instead of `www.paypal.com`, but when I do that the button doesn't even display anymore, so I kept: `www.paypal.com`. Then I replaced the CLIENT_ID with the one for my business account, which I created in sandbox:
[image]

As I have 2 REST API apps, I tried both, but every time I clicked on the button the paypal page closed almost instantly. Whereas with my personal/production `CLIENT_ID` there's no problem at all. So I realized that there was an error with `CLIENT_ID`, and I also noticed 4 other errors in the console:

```
Blocking a multi-origin request (Cross-Origin Request): the "Same Origin" policy does not allow access to the remote resource located at https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/xoplatform/logger/api/logger?disableSetCookie=true. Reason: the CORS header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" does not correspond to "https://localhost".
```

```
Cross-Origin Request blocked: the "Same Origin" policy does not allow access to the remote resource located at https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/xoplatform/logger/api/logger?disableSetCookie=true. Reason: CORS request failed. Status code: (null).
```

[image]

So I realized that my WAMP server couldn't connect to other external sites such as paypal, so I did this:

1. I activated in Apache: headers_module, proxy_module and proxy_http_module
2. I added at the end of `httpd.conf` :

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://localhost"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Authorization"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
```

But it had no effect! And so I noticed two other errors:

1. XHR POST https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions [HTTP/2 404 Not Found 355ms]
   **REQUEST :**

```
{"plan_id":"P-2HT47386S0788824HMTFNRUY","subscriber":{"email_address":"sb-sbngw26946178@business.example.com"}}
```

**RESPONSE :**

```
{"name":"RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND","message":"The specified resource does not exist.","debug_id":"f5894368720a1","details":[{"issue":"INVALID_RESOURCE_ID","description":"Requested resource ID was not found."}],"links":[{"href":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/v1/billing/subscriptions#RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND","rel":"information_link","method":"GET"}]}
```

2. create_order_error buttons:1489:140112
   And here's the Object to return :

```
Error: Create Subscription Api response error:

{
    "name": "RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND",
    "message": "The specified resource does not exist.",
    "debug_id": "f5894368720a1",
    "details": [
        {
            "issue": "INVALID_RESOURCE_ID",
            "description": "Requested resource ID was not found."
        }
    ],
    "links": [
        {
            "href": "https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/v1/billing/subscriptions#RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND",
            "rel": "information_link",
            "method": "GET"
        }
    ]
}
```

[image]

Personally, I realized that there was a problem with `plan_id`. My `plan_id` was automatically generated when I created my paypal button:
[image]

That's where I'm at at the moment, my aim is to test whether the transactions are carried out correctly and then use the data received to create, for example, an unsubscribe button which, as far as I know, paypal doesn't offer. If anyone has an answer to my questions, I thank them in advance!